# Converting json to interface

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following problem:

```
 public static T Converter<T>(string message)
        {
          var types=  TypesImplementingInterface<T>();

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, type);
                    return (T)result;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }


 public static List<Type> TypesImplementingInterface<T>()
        {
            return AppDomain
                .CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                .Where(typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom).ToList();
        }

 class PlainMessage : IMessage
    {
        public int Issi { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
 IMessage result =  Converter<IMessage>(json);
```

It works but it is not a good solution because of trying to deserialize to every subtype.

I found an article http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/08/30/deserializing-interface-properties-using-json-net/. It is almost this what I want to achieve but I dont want to have a wrapper like "ThingContainer". I want to deserialize class itself. 
I was thinking about sending a property TYPE in json and deserialize it into JObject and deserialize it into that type, but I don't know if its perfect solution. 
In general - is there possibility to deserialize an interface?

Comment: Reflection is not a problem here, because I can obtain all implementations from external source